# How to implement parallax effect to different sections of a page?

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, position, parallax

I'm looking to implement a parallax effect on a website. I want to know if it's possible to implement this kind of scrolling effect on different parts of the page without affecting each other.

I created a little oversimplified example of what I want to do. I want the sprites (the red circles and green squares) to move upwards at a different rate than the actual background. However, the examples from a) and b) are in different DIV's, and they have irregular borders which are in another divs inside the same container. Like this:

```
<div id="section-1">
<div id="1-top"></div>
<div id="1-content"></div>
<div id="1-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

is there any way to move the sprites upwards through the div, and the border, but without being visible over the main background (blue in this case).

Would the squares in section b) move up to section a) or is there a way to limit how many pixels or percentage points the objects can move?.

[image: Example]

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that 'choppy' movement when scrolling with the mouse, It also depends on the browser, of course. Opera has a really smooth scrolling, even with the mouse, which makes the effect much more pleasant (but the rest of the browsers i've tried don't), so thanks for the suggestion. I'll look into it. That plugin doesn't do exactly what I was thinking at the beginning, but I think it will still look like a really nice effect in the context I'm trying to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to accomplish is very achievable using two scripts.

Besides using a **jQuery parallax script**, you should use a **jQuery Scrolling script** to handle your red circles and green squares requirements.

There are quite a few Demos to check out, and picking the right scrolling script should come before the parallax script, since those objects are contained inside the div's that the parallax would then move with the background.

Since both scripts will be using event listeners for vertical/scrolling activity, they **both will work in harmony** to create the proper animations, with each script handling it's specific tasks.

That alone allows for better flexibility as you then have **two different API's** for very specific functionality.

Here's a recent [SITE](http://smashinghub.com/7-jquery-parallax-and-scrolling-effect-plugins.htm) showing the latest plugins to get started on looking for the right scrolling and parallax script.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there has been a lot of jquery parallax related answers.

I played around with it on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/thinkingsites/88sqh/2/

The trick to parallax is that the further back it is, it takes the same time to move a shorter distance. While I don't have any specific equation for setting them up, it can be done with a little work.

The irregular background won't be bothered by the animation of the child elements.

Looking at the sidebar here, it seems there are a lot of answers for parallax jquery, though some of it seems based around the nikebetterworld example, which is not what I think you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, Most seemed unrelated to what I'm aiming to do. Nikebetterworld seems to have been a catalyzer for lots of questions on this matter.
Thanks for the jsfiddle little example. I will have to test this on my lunch break, as it's my little side project :)